# 検索エンジンの検索結果に自サイトの主要コンテンツを表示させる方法を知りたい

Tags: html

自社のホームページを検索すると、トップページのみしか表示されません。

他社様のホームページを検索してみると、トップページ以外の各ページが下段に表示されます。（添付画像）

同じ様に表示させるには、どの様なタグを組み込めば良いのでしょうか。
ご回答をお待ちしております。

参考画像の様に、表示させたいのですが方法をご教示くださるとたすかります。

宜しくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 検索エンジンが表示しているサイトリンクのことを指していますか？

Answer (score 3):

> 他社様のホームページを検索してみると、トップページ以外の各ページが下段に表示されます。

そのような項目は**サイトリンク**と呼ばれています。

> 同じ様に表示させるには、どの様なタグを組み込めば良いのでしょうか。

サイトリンクを表示するかどうかは Google が判断し自動的に表示するため、サイト作成者が**表示の有無を制御することは出来ません**。

> #### サイトリンク<sup>[[1]](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=ja)</sup>
>
> サイトリンクは、ユーザーの役に立つと Google が判断した場合のみ、検索結果に表示されます。サイトの構造が原因で Google のアルゴリズムが適切なサイトリンクを見つけることができない場合や、サイトリンクとユーザーのクエリとに関連性がないと思われる場合、サイトリンクは表示されません。

---

参考:

1. [サイトリンク - Search Console ヘルプ](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=ja)

Comment: 有り難うございました。

Comment: @かぶきん さん> 解決されたようで良かったです。問題が解決した場合は、[質問を解決済みに](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1735/32986)してくださると助かります。